# The suggestion form disappears before clicking on <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I'm new in HTML and CSS programming. I have a problem here

I use a `<div>` tag to make a suggestion form for the `<input>` tag. I put the `<div>` tag to appear when the `:focus` event occurs in the `<input>` tag. The problem is that before I can click on the `<a>` tag, the `<div>` tag is already gone

I guess it's because when the `<a>` tag is clicked, the `:focus` event has ended

Does anyone have any ideas to help me with?

My code:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.suggest {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

input:focus ~ .suggest {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="suggest">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="item">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="item">Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the hover code? your display:block triggers on input:focus and stays block as long as input is in focus. I ran your snippet, suggestions stay visible

Comment: sorry sir it's :focus

Comment: i set display: none to suggestions block. when focus to input, suggestions display block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use **:focus-within**.

It represents an element that is itself matched by the :focus pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by :focus.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.suggest {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

input:focus ~ .suggest {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper:focus-within div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="suggest">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="item">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="item">Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked but anyway to select the text inside it?
my code: https://jsfiddle.net/a58bpjz0/

Comment: It works only elements that have a focus() method. So, you can use with tabindex attr: https://codepen.io/phyesix/pen/gOvEENN